# Forgot to disable fast-startup and now I have only Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, disk, file-format, disk-management

So my friend  have a really old laptop it got so slow it is unworkable on, I suggested him to **install Ubuntu** and **remove Windows 10** which was installed. I was a supervisor of the process although it is my first time "installing" Linux, but I have a high technical knowledge.
the problem start when my friend have 1 HDD drive  with 3 partitions and all are MBR and **NTFS format**. he have data on D:\ and E:\ so we formatted just the C:\ (WinOS) and after problems and struggles we installed it with Grub and it boots very well.
Now we have the **problem of the D:\ and E:\ drives loading on read-only because we haven't disabled fast startup** on Windows before uninstalling it...

Edit: not long after we tried booting into windows with a CD and then tried to turn off hibernation options using the installation cmd, it didn't work as it can't be configured from within the installer, my friend booted into ubuntu did some suggested updates (by the Ubuntu OS) and restarted and for some unknown reasons, they allowed for writing on them along the reading allowed before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: NTFS will require maintenance you can only do from Windows like chkdsk or defrag. So best to plan backup of data and reformat to a Linux type format like ext4. You can mount read only so as not to damage hibernation and copy the data for backup.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for quick answer and sorry for late reply, the problem is we don't have access to windows as we deleted it, it was unusable, and we have no connector to usb or another windows pc with empty slot.

Answer (score 1):

ntfs is a proprietary file system. Therefore, the only thorough tools to check and repair an ntfs file system are the tools of MS Windows.

As a general rule, only keep ntfs partitions around if you can connect them now and then to a windows machine.

In this case, the ntfs partitions are on an internal drive in a computer without windows. Therefore, the only sound advice here is to reformat these partitions to a linux file system such as `ext4`, the default file system of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu still mounts the partitions read-only. This is because writing could further damage the file system. It means you still can read the data. Update your backup of that data before converting the file system. Reformatting the partitions will erase all data.

Comment: thank you, but the ubuntu has long adapted NTFS in read-write mode and also we have worked with some NTFS drives with no problem in ubuntu.

Comment: I am not denying that although your current experience suggests otherwise. Feel perfectly free to use ntfs without being able to connect to Windows, it is your call.

Comment: ok, thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Please "accept" the question if it answers your query, even if the answer is not always what one would prefer to hear.